# select multiple columns in pandas data frame with column index as sequential number

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I am trying to extract the 7th to 14th columns in a data frame. However

`df[0:3]` only gives the 1st to 3rd rows.

Does anyone knows what should I do if I want to find out the columns?

I know how to do it with column names such as `df['a']` but as the names are too many, I just want to type something like `df[,7:14]` in R.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Looks that I found it....

By using iloc..

```
df.iloc[:,your_col_index]
```

Comment: Would be `df.iloc[:,6:14]` in your case.